# Read content from InputStream in bitbucket api methods

Tags: java, git, bitbucket, inputstream, bitbucket-api

I'm trying to read a file for a pre-receive hook with the bitbucket api. The point is, I need to check some concrete file and content stuff in order to aprove or reject the commit.  You can see the code here:

```
request.getRefChanges().stream()
.filter(change -> change.getRef().getId().equalsIgnoreCase("refs/heads/master"))
.forEach(refChange -> {
     scmService.getBulkContentCommandFactory(request.getRepository())                
     .contents(new BulkContentCommandParameters.Builder(refChange.getToHash())
            .sinceCommitId(refChange.getFromHash())
            .build(), new BulkContentCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFile(@Nonnull BulkFile file, @Nonnull InputStream content) {
                        this.processFile(file, content);
                    }
                        private void processFile(BulkFile file, InputStream content) {
                            log.info("Streaming file {} with content id {}, file: {}, size: {}",
                                    file.getPath(), file.getContentId(), file.getSize());
                            try {
                                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                                //IOUtils.copy(content, writer, "UTF-8");
                                log.info("file content: {}", readSB(content));
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                            }
                        }
                    }).call();});
```

The problem is, the InputStream I get from the `onFile` method of *BulkContentCallback* is like just giving me the first line of the file. I've tried with different implementations in the readSB method like
**InputStream first implementation**

```
    StringBuilder textBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try (Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
              (inputStream, Charset.forName(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())))) {
                int c = 0;
                while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
                    textBuilder.append((char) c);
                }
            }

    return textBuilder.toString();
```

Or **InputStream second implementation**:

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 int nRead;
 byte[] data = new byte[1024];
 while ((nRead = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
            buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
        }

 buffer.flush();
 byte[] byteArray = buffer.toByteArray();

 String text = new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

 return text;
```

Or **InputStream third implementation**:

```
try (BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
        return buffer.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))
}
```

But the result is always the same, just prints the first line.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Detected as a *bug* in Bitbucket version **5.13.0** and older (tested in **5.10.1** and later versions and is not working). I just updated to **5.14.0** and works correctly.

Hope it helps.